# The advanced page cannot be opened when we want to add Active Directory user

Tags: active-directory

When we want to replace a local service account for a domain service account. Systematical we have this error (The advanced page cannot be opened) :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/18/5/1556879210-the-server-is-not-operational.png

This is what we try to do : 
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/18/5/1556879210-service-login.png

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/18/5/1556879210-nologo.png

Note that we don't see the logo and all the CN ...

Thank you for your help :)

PS : The machines are in the same domain, they can be ping each other with the IP or DNS Name.

Comment: I think it's telling you the truth: The server is not operational. It likely just can't reach the server through the network.

Comment: As I said, the servers are in the same domain and they can ping each others. If the AD servers cannot be reachable , no one should be in the domain I think .

Comment: Ping tells you the server is online, but a firewall could still be blocking LDAP connections. You can try testing that connection using `Test-NetConnection domain.com -Port 389` in PowerShell. You can also try running `nslookup domain.com` at the command line and make sure that DNS is only giving you the IP of the one server you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the Test-NetConnection.
It work for a specific machine in the domain (machin1.domain.com) but not when I try on "domain.com" ...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Gabriel I found the mistake ...

In the DNS Forward Lookup Zone, I have fill two host with the same IP Adress.

> AD.domain.com | Host(A) | 10.10.10.10
>
> domain.com | Host(A) | 10.10.10.10

Unfortunatly, only the AD.domain.com was responding and domain.com was not reachable.

I've removed the row for AD.domain.com and now everything works well !

Thank you for your help !